# How can I automate the running of updatedb on an encrypted partition?

Tags: encryption, home-directory, autostart

On an encrypted partition, normally the updatedb does not index the encrypted home directory. To run locate (updatedb) while the user is logged in, one hast to keep that part of the locate database under user's encrypted $HOME.

```
export LOCATE_PATH="$HOME/var/mlocate.db"
```

and then to run updatedb to index the files in $HOME by:

```
updatedb -l 0 -o $HOME/var/mlocate.db -U $HOME
```

This gives a complete index of $HOME and the database isn't visible unless $HOME is mounted and decrypted.

As the ubuntu's rc file infrastructure keeps changing, I'm confused what is the right place (i.e. to which file) to add these lines?

Edit: Currently running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you running ?

Comment: 14.04. Thanks  solsTiCe, version added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the `/etc/rc*` structure at all - that is for system startup, run level transitions, and NOT for user stuff. When the `rc` scripts are running, the system is only partially started, the only `UID` is `0` (`root`).

I run `updatedb` from my `crontab`, at 02:05 daily. Here's the line from my `crontab`:

```
02 05  *   *   *     /usr/bin/updatedb -l 0 -o /home/w3/var/mlocate/mlocate.db -U /home/w3
```

Note that this `cron` job must be scheduled to run at a time when user `w3` is logged in, and the unencrypted directory is mounted.